# istream extraction values with formatted string

Tags: c++, text, formatting, iostream, istream

I have this formatted string in an istream.

> (5, -4)

Let say :

1. open parenthesis
2. an integer number
3. comma and space
4. another integer number
5. close parenthesis

I would like to know what is the best approach to extract both integers and validate the string formatting.

This is in a class like this :

```
class MyPoint
{
public:
   MyPoint() = default;
   ~MyPoint() = default;
   ...
   friend ostream & operator>>(ostream & lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);
   ...
private:
   int x, y;
};

ostream & operator>>(ostream & lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    // ???
}
```

Many thanks to all.

Here is my header file

```
#ifndef MYPOINT_H
#define MYPOINT_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyPoint
{
public:
    MyPoint() : mX{ 0 }, mY{ 0 } { ; }
    MyPoint(int x, int y) : mX{ x }, mY{ y } { ; }
    ~MyPoint() = default;

    int x() const { return mX; }
    int y() const { return mY; }
    void setX(int x) { mX = x; }
    void setY(int y) { mY = y; }

    MyPoint operator-() const { return MyPoint(-mX, mY); }
    MyPoint operator+(MyPoint rhs) const { rhs.mX += mX; rhs.mY += mY; return rhs; }
    MyPoint operator-(MyPoint rhs) const { rhs.mX = mX - rhs.mX; rhs.mY = mY - rhs.mY; return rhs; }
    MyPoint operator*(MyPoint rhs) const { rhs.mX *= mX; rhs.mY *= mY; return rhs; }
    MyPoint operator/(MyPoint rhs) const { rhs.mX = mX / rhs.mX; rhs.mY = mY / rhs.mY; return rhs; }
    MyPoint operator%(MyPoint rhs) const { rhs.mX = mX % rhs.mX; rhs.mY = mY % rhs.mY; return rhs; }

    friend MyPoint operator+(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);
    friend MyPoint operator-(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);
    friend MyPoint operator*(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);
    friend MyPoint operator/(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);
    friend MyPoint operator%(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & lhs, MyPoint const & rhs);
    friend istream & operator>>(istream & lhs, MyPoint & rhs);

private:
    int mX, mY;

};

#endif //MYPOINT_H
```

And here my source file

```
#include "MyPoint.h"


MyPoint operator+(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    return MyPoint(lhs + rhs.mX, lhs + rhs.mY);
}
MyPoint operator-(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    return MyPoint(lhs - rhs.mX, lhs - rhs.mY);
}
MyPoint operator*(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    return MyPoint(lhs * rhs.mX, lhs * rhs.mY);
}
MyPoint operator/(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    return MyPoint(lhs / rhs.mX, lhs / rhs.mY);
}
MyPoint operator%(int lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    return MyPoint(lhs % rhs.mX, lhs % rhs.mY);
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & lhs, MyPoint const & rhs) {
    return lhs << "(" << rhs.mX << "," << rhs.mY << ")";
}
istream & operator >> (istream & lhs, MyPoint & rhs) {
    return lhs >> "(" >> rhs.mX >> "," >> rhs.mY >> ")"; // HERE is the compiling error
}
```

And finally, the tests in the main

```
MyPoint p1, p2(2, -2);
cout << p1 << endl;
cout << p2 << endl;
```

With this file, I got this error :
Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For situations like this, I've often found it handy to define an overload of `operator>>` to read a predefined string from a stream:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, char const *pat) {

    char ch;
    while (isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(is.peek())))
        is.get(ch);

    while (*pat && is && *pat == is.peek() && is.get(ch)) {
        ++pat;
    }

    // if we didn't reach the end of the pattern, matching failed (mismatch, premature EOF, etc.)
    if (*pat) {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }

    return is;
}
```

With this, reading your format might look something like this:

```
istream & operator>>(istream & lhs, MyPoint & rhs) {
    return lhs >> "(" >> rhs.x >> "," >> rhs.y >> ")";
}
```

This will do like most typical overloads and set the stream's fail bit if the pattern you've given isn't matched. As it stands now, each string in the input can be preceded by arbitrary white space (just like conversions for numbers and such).

There is technically a minor bug here: as it stands right now, this uses the global locale's definition of whitespace. To be really correct, it should probably use the definition provided in the locale associated with the input stream.

Also note that I had to change your definition of `operator>>` bit; in the question it looks like an overload of `operator<<`, with just those two characters changed to get `operator>>` instead.

For a quick example:

```
#include <iostream>

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, char const *pat) {
    // implementation above
}

class Point {
    int x, y;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Point &p) { 
        return is >> "(" >> p.x >>"," >> p.y >> ")";
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Point const &p) { 
        return os << "(" << p.x <<", " << p.y << ")";
    }
};

int main() {
    Point p;

    std::cout << "Please enter a point: ";
    std::cin >> p;
    std::cout << "Thanks. Point: " << p << '\n';
}
```

Tested with VC++ 2013, VC++ 2015, and g++ 6.1 (but this isn't pushing the limits of compilers at all, so I'd expect it to work fine even with compilers so old they're horribly broken in general (e.g., gcc 2.x or VC++ 6.0).

Comment: Hi Jerry. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Also, I cannot find any documentation about this technics. I mean, what is the technical term to use if I want to find some information about the iostream >> (char*)something?

Many thanks for all the details!

Comment: @Aesope: I don't know that there is a lot of detail beyond the fact that this is just another overload of an operator. There's an existing overload to read a string into (the buffer referred to by) a pointer. This is just another overload based on `const`ness of the pointer. Overloading on const-ness should be covered in any decent book on C++; this is just one more application of a well-known capability.

Comment: Hi Jerry. It is what I thought. Meanwhile, I got a strange error while compiling. Do I need a special header file? or something else? I got this compiling error from MSVC++ 2015 : 
error C2679: binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: @Aesope: You have to include *something* that at least declares `std::istream` (e.g., `<iostream>`, `<iosfwd>`, etc.) This code has been tested with VC++ 2015 though...